# How do I create an installer for a new release?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, release

There is a newly developed program release that needs a new installer. I have in my possesion the old one along with its installer. I am a rookie and I found out that NSIS is the way to go. How can I find the dependencies of the new release and what registries it needs in order to work? The program is in C++ using Qt. I am searching for the answer a little more than a week. Any help or link to a tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [PACE Suite](http://pacesuite.com/features/) - it captures all changes the installer makes in the system, and you can use it to create the new installer. You need to buy it for commercial use, but for your test the free trial should suffice. 
However, PACE can only create silent installers, meaning there will be no dialog windows, and the end user will not be given options to choose from (e.g. install location). In that case you can look for other packaging tools - like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools).